# trigger speech input chrome mountain lion shift +cmd +.

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion, speech-recognition

hello every one can anyone help me in bringing back shortcut for speech input in  chrome with mountain lion( shift +cmd +. )
the problem is that mountain lion uses shift +cmd +. for showing hidden files in save dialogue ,i opened a bug with chrome 3 mounths ago and still no patch so  anyone knows how to disable shift +cmd +. system wide or some sort of script for clicking the microphone whick i could assign to any keyboard shortcut using better touch tool 
thank you very much
ps a bookmarklet would be just fine!